# elasticseach How to add search type in request body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, chewy-gem

I have a query where I am using search_type as

```
GET /test_videos/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
                  "query": "funny",
                  "fields": ["title"]
                 }
              }
            }
}
}
```

which works fine and gives the result I want.

I can also specify the explain in the body like this:

```
GET /test_claim_videos/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{ "explain" : true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
                  "query": "funny",
                  "fields": ["title", "asset_name", "description", "tags.name", "asset_group_name.humanized", "credit"]
                 }
              }
            }
}
}
```

But I want to specify the search_type as dfs_then_fetch inside the body.
If I do

```
GET /test_claim_videos/_search
{ "search_type" : "dfs_query_then_fetch",
  "explain" : true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
                  "query": "funny",
                  "fields": ["title", "asset_name", "description", "tags.name", "asset_group_name.humanized", "credit"]
                 }
              }
            }
}
}
```

It raises error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [search_type].",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 19
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [search_type].",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 19
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Why can't I specify search type in body here and how to fix that? I need it to be in body as I am using a third party gem chewy which doesn't allow to pass URL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have no ability to do it. You can read more in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_parameters_4):

> Out of the above, the search_type and the request_cache must be passed as query-string parameters.

Comment: So how should I solve the problem of sorting by relevance score where I want score of same documents as same and not depend on shard numbers